# Designing a traffic light application

Tags: java, timer

My teacher asked us to design a traffic light application. The application will have three button:

1. **start:** to start the traffic light. When we press the button we see red circle, 2 seconds after we see green circle, 3 seconds after we see orange circle for 0.4 seconds and then we see red circle and we repeat the same thing again.
2. **stop:** we see white circle
3. **breakdown:** in this mode we see orange circle for 0.5 seconds and then white circle for 0.6 seconds and the orange circle again.

The first question is how many timer we should use. I answered that we can use only one timer that will post event each 0.1 seconds. The teacher said that it's a bad idea to that and we should use 5 timers. He said that I will have a problem if I launch many programs on my machine (overload).

Why my solution is not good? Using many timer won't complicate the solution?

**Edit:**

He said that we need 5 timer because there's 5 five events (changing from red to green, green to orange, orange to red, orange to white, white to orange). He said if we add more colors we add also timers.

Here's its logic:

```
timer1 has interval of 2 seconds
timer2 has interval of 3 seconds
timer3 has interval of 0.4 seconds
timer4 has interval of 0.5 seconds
timer5 has interval of 0.6 seconds
```

At start only timer1 is enabled, when it post an event we change the color of the circle from red to green we disable timer1 and start timer2

When timer2 post an event we change the color of the circle from green to orange. We disable timer2 and we start timer3.

When timer3 post an event we change the color of the circle from orange to red. We disable timer3 and we start timer1.

We apply the same logic when we are in breakdown mode.

Comment: To understand why your instructor thinks five timers are needed, I suppose we need to know what the other constraints are on the behavior of the application. How precise must the different timings be? What else can be *expected* to run on the same machine? Are there any other expected user interactions? Personally, the number *five* smells a bit of [magic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) -- I'm somewhat suspicious of your instructor's conclusion based on that fact alone.

Comment: @HenryKeiter There isn't any other constraints. I edited my answer to see why he thinks that we need five timers.

Answer (score 2):

The standard wisdom here is that if you are writing a computer program that controls a traffic light, you:

- use the simplest possible logic so it can be determined to behave correctly in all cases
- and do not use this computer to do other things besides control a traffic light.

Increased program complexity does not generally lead towards predictable behavior. (It leads to more bugs.)

---

So the standard wisdom would say to use 1 timer because it is more likely to be robust.

```
timer1 has interval of 2 seconds
timer2 has interval of 3 seconds
timer3 has interval of 0.4 seconds
timer4 has interval of 0.5 seconds
timer5 has interval of 0.6 seconds
```

I'm not an expert in multithreading but, assuming each timer is a thread, I doubt this will result in more granular time-keeping. This requires the thread scheduler to do more context switching. We now have 5 separate contexts, as opposed to 1, needing attention for the color changes to be accurate. The probability that any one timer is switched to at the point it needs to trigger is lower.

In a worst-case scenario, let's say `timer3` is neglected for `0.11` seconds at the time it is meant to trigger, you could have colors appear out of order. Now the timers need to also communicate with each other to ensure our intended behavior. Because of the introduced complexity, we must increase complexity yet again to prevent error.

Comment: +1 for "Increased program complexity does not generally lead towards predictable behavior." I think you should go all the way to the conclusion though; "one timer is sufficient for this application."

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use timer at all. You would be better off looking at the [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) for this sort of application.

Comment: This is arguably a kind of timer.